React native inverted border radius
I was looking for solutions to this for a while now, but I found no answer to this. Image will show the case better.

Above is the piece of design I have. This is a bottom menu, but on the top of what looks like a rectangle is this piece of inverted border radius. What I cannot find is how can I make only the radius colored, but the rest transparent. Every solution I found was with full color. What I need is just those corner inverted borders and everything from the top of the rectangle to be transparent. Also to be working on phones.
Does anyone have any idea how to achieve such effect? Thank you beforehand.
